# Track c# Web API / SOAP Request and Response

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, asmx, svc

I have written couple of Web API + REST/SOAP webservice (.svc /.asmx), which are deployed in IIS Windows server 2012/ 2008 not in Azure. And those APIs are used by external applications, I need a mechanism to track the web request and its response either in 3rd party tool / via coding.

Higher Level : Number of times the request is called
Lower Level : from which source, what the request header / parameter and its response.

Answer (score 0):

Using filters/handlers in web api you can log incomming requests and your responses.

If you are looking for an elegant way you may use appdynamics or riverbed applications

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about the purpose here but in case you want to track this data temporarily without touching the service, an alternative is to use a network traffic monitoring  tool like the one at below location. I use this normally to debug my application.

[MS Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

Comment: will https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226 (MS message analyzer) capture all the incoming request and response

Comment: Yes, you can configure it to capture everything. You can either listen to incoming or outgoing traffic from an IP address or you can also configure it to listen outgoing/incoming traffic from an IP. But I am not too sure if this can be run as a service.